# Computing $\bigcup_{n=1,5}X_{n}$? when $X_{n}=n+1,n+2,...,2n$

Tags: education, sets, subset

How do I correctly compute $\bigcup_{n=1,5}X_{n}$? when $X_{n}=n+1,n+2,...,2n$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N^{+}}$?

When I do the calculation manually, I get the following results:

$n=1:\{2\}$

$n=2:\{3, 4\}$

$n=3:\{4, 5, 6\}$

$n=4: \{5, 6, 7, 8\}$

$n=5: \{6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$

So the finally answer is $\bigcup_{n=1,5}X_{n}=\{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$

I created the code below purely by luck, and it happens that the last subset of the set in the result aligns with my final answer. How do I improve the code so that it only gives the final result?

```
Table[Table[k + 1, {k, 1, 2 b - 1}], {b, 1, 6}];
```

> ```
> {{2}, {2, 3, 4}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}, 
>  {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}}
> ```

Comment: `Union @@ Range @@@ Table[{n + 1, 2 n}, {n, 5}]`?

Comment: @ Michael E2 Thanks! what does the @@ and @@@ do? also, I am trying to simulate $\bigcap_{k=1}^{5}[\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}X_{n}]$. Any suggestion?

Comment: When you don't understand a symbol or operator, highlight it and press `F1` for help.

Comment: @ Michael E2 I could not figure out how to do $\bigcap_{k=1}^{5}[\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}X_{n}]$. May I ask how you could do it?

Comment: They are versions of [`Apply`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616).  See [Scope > Level Specifications](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html#794993555).

Comment: @Tmm See my answer for the intersection of the unions.

Answer (score 2):

`Range` produces what I would call an enumeration list:

```
Range[1, 4]

(* {1, 2, 3, 4} *)
```

The default step is 1.

Let's apply this to your equation:

```
Column[
 Table[Row[{n, ":", Range[n + 1, 2 n]}], {n, 1, 5}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Here is the list of lists:

```
Table[Range[1 + n, 2 n], {n, 1, 5}]

(* {{2}, {3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {6, 7, 8, 9, 10}} *)
```

Now we use `Apply` to replace the Head of the list with `Union`. The `@@` symbol is a shortcut for `Apply`.

```
Union @@ Table[Range[1 + n, 2 n], {n, 1, 5}]
```

or

```
Apply[Union, Table[Range[1 + n, 2 n], {n, 1, 5}]]

(* {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10} *)
```

Comment: If I want to do $\bigcap_{k=1}^{5}[\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}X_{n}]$, is this code correct? Apply[Intersection, 
 Table[Range[Table[Range[1 + n, 2 n], {n, 1, k}]], {k, 1, 5}]]

Comment: @ Jack LaVigne If I want to do $\bigcap_{k=1}^{5}[\bigcup_{n=1}^{k}X_{n}]$, is this code correct? Apply[Intersection, 
 Table[Range[Table[Range[1 + n, 2 n], {n, 1, k}]], {k, 1, 5}]]

Comment: @Tmm I think this is the way to do it. Take the expression from the answer and replace 5 with `k`. Then build a table around that from k=1 to 5. Finally `Apply` `Intersection` to the result. `Apply[Intersection, 
 Table[Apply[Union, Table[Range[1 + n, 2 n], {n, 1, k}]], {k, 1, 5}]]`

Answer (score 2):

The union can be given by

```
u[n_Integer /; n > 0] := Range[2, 2 n]
```

Then

```
u[5]
```

gives

> `{2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}`

The intersection of the unions is given by

```
Intersection @@ Table[u[i], {i, 5}]
```

> `{2}`

but it always be {2} for any `n`, so we may as well write

```
iu[n_Integer /; n > 0] = {2}
```

Answer (score 1):

First an $X_n$ operator/constructor, to simplify the approach in my comment:

```
X = Function[n, Range[n + 1, 2 n]]
```

or

```
X = Range[# + 1, 2 #] &
```

Next, $\bigcup_{n=1}^5 X_n$:

```
Union @@ Array[X, {5}]   (* Array[..] constructs {X[1], X[2], X[3], X[4], X[5]} *)
(*  {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}  *)
```

`Table[X[n], {n, 5}]` can be used instead of `Array`, too.

Then, as requested in a comment, $\bigcap_{k=1}^5 \left( \bigcup_{n=1}^k X_n \right)$:

```
Intersection @@ Table[Union @@ Array[X, {k}], {k, 5}]
(*  {2}  *)
```

---

If preferred, the 4th argument of `Array` can be applied to the examples as follows:

```
Array[X, {5}, 1, Union]                                (* Union *)
(*  {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}  *)

Array[Array[X, {#}, 1, Union] &, {5}, 1, Intersection] (* Intersection of Union *)
(*  {2}  *)
```

The last one is more readable with a symbolic argument to `Function`:

```
Array[Function[k, Array[X, {k}, 1, Union]], {5}, 1, Intersection]
(*  {2}  *)
```